# DOM running slow on jQuery click function

Tags: jquery

I have a small issue with the DOM taking up to 30 seconds to recognize that a click has been made. When I click back and forth between "A" and "C" the menu that shows up takes more and more clicks to show up. The DOM sometimes takes up to 30 seconds to recognize the change has been made and I usually end up having to double-click after a while to get the click recognized.

Is there a proper way to handle adding/removing classes using jQuery that doesn't throttle the DOM?

The code is here: http://jsfiddle.net/chrisabrams/F7nQ4/6/

Comment: Have you tried disabling Firebug?

Comment: I just disabled all firebug-related plugins and there was no difference in performance. Clicking is still slow.

Comment: I'm not seeing the performance hit you're describing looking at your jsfiddle.

Comment: So when you click back and forth between the "A" and the "C" you don't have any delays for the menus opening/closing or you do not have to double-click?

Comment: Me neither, have you tried other browsers?

Comment: I also tried Chrome and it gave me the same problem. I've even changed computers and get the same issue. The first click or two work but after that it starts to get slow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have any problem in your code. Try it in other browser/computer and you'll see.

Hope this helps

Comment: I have tried this on 3 computers and 3 browsers. After a few clicks, the menu does not show up without needing multiple clicks.